# numpad enter remapped in new macOS updates for alacritty

Tags: macos, command-line, keyboard, terminal, alacritty

I have been having annoying problems with my terminal [Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty). In macOS after recent updates my numpad enter is not giving me what I would expect when I press it.

Normal Keyboard enter.

```
❯ whoami
aaron
```

Numpad enter.

```
❯ whoami^C
```

One of these is not like the other. `^C` is equivalent to `ctrl + c`. Which is how you quit most cli apps.
This is even more problematic if I use this enter after a password like when logging into ssh. It would immediately disconnect the terminal session after establishing the connection. This looked like a problem with the client or server not a problem with my keyboard. After many hours looking at all kinds of logs and network packet captures to isolate this problem I am not sure what is going on.
This is an incredibly difficult problem to identify, especially when this all worked as expected a few weeks ago.

```
sw_vers
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     14.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Fix alacritty

Check what is going on when you type on your keyboard.
more info

```
alacritty --print-events

[3.734266542s] [INFO ] [alacritty] winit event: WindowEvent { window_id: WindowId(WindowId(4905463248)), event: KeyboardInput { device_id: DeviceId(DeviceId), event: KeyEvent { physical_key: Code(Enter), logical_key: Named(Enter), text: None, location: Standard, state: Released, repeat: false, platform_specific: KeyEventExtra { text_with_all_modifiers: Some("\r"), key_without_modifiers: Named(Enter) } }, is_synthetic: false } }
....
[5.825335959s] [INFO ] [alacritty] winit event: WindowEvent { window_id: WindowId(WindowId(4905463248)), event: KeyboardInput { device_id: DeviceId(DeviceId), event: KeyEvent { physical_key: Code(NumpadEnter), logical_key: Named(Enter), text: Some("\r"), location: Numpad, state: Pressed, repeat: false, platform_specific: KeyEventExtra { text_with_all_modifiers: Some("\u{3}"), key_without_modifiers: Named(Enter) } }, is_synthetic: false } }
```

Trying to isolate this problem took a lot longer than I expected.

Edit the alacritty config.

```
nvim ~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.toml
```

Add

```
[[keyboard.bindings]]
key = "NumpadEnter"
chars = "\r"
```

This fixes the problem for the one application with which I am having problems, Alacritty.

Test Numpad enter.

```
❯ whoami
aaron
```